# Java Time format return as time object

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

If I do:

```
ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
```

It returns a `String`, rather I'd like it to return a `ZonedDateTime` object. Is there a clean way of doing that. This is the obvious solution:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
```

Is there an easier way to do that? That just seems a little too verbose.

Comment: Hum, how about `ZonedDateTime.now()`?

Comment: A `ZonedDateTime` doesn't have a format.  What you're asking for is just `ZonedDateTime.now()`.

Comment: Yes but I want to format it in whatever what I want. I can choose any `DateTimeFormatter` and it'll return based on that format. I've tested this with multiple formats and I have gotten multiple return values based on the format I chose

Comment: @Richard it sounds like you're not getting the distinction between a `ZonedDateTime` and a formatted output.  You should be using `ZonedDateTime` without any formatting inside your program and then a `DateTimeFormatter` when you need to pass it outside your program or expose it to a user.

Comment: Is there a difference between this question and the following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311293/java-8-setting-global-time-formatters

Comment: @Richard you should explain in more details what you want (and ***why*** you want it) - at the moment your question does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

just use `ZonedDateTime.now()`

source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now--

Comment: this is not what I want. I want to be able to control the format that it return the `.now()` in. I can do that with the `.format` option; I have tested choosing multiple formats and it's worked like I want. Returning the date in various formats. Now I want to return that format as a zoneddatetime object rather than a string since the `.format()` method returns a string

Comment: as @Louis says, I think you should use a ZonedDateTime without any formatting inside your program

Comment: @Richard that doesn't make any sense.  There is no such thing as a format in a `ZonedDateTime` object.  There is only format when you transform a `ZonedDateTime` into a `String`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) it is

Comment: @Richard, yes, and?  A `ZonedDateTime` is like an `int`: the numbers 16 and 0x10 are the same thing, but an `int` is just a number, without any format.  There is only format when you convert the `int` into the `String`.